# File upload using SOAP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, soap, web, soap-client

I am trying to create a web application which will allow the user to upload a file. The file will be encrypted and transferred to a web service via SOAP. The web service will carry out simple operations such as 'storeFileToCloud(byte[])' and 'downloadFile(string)'.

So far, using Google App Engine, I have created the web services, however, I'm not sure how to encode the file using SOAP. I've also created the form for the user to upload his/her file, but I'm stuck on what to do after this. Any tips or guides will be extremely helpful.

The tools I'm using include Java, Google App Engine and Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JAX-RPC uses xsd:base64Binary. See the [JAX-RPC Spec, chapter 10](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/j2ee/jwsa/JWSA_CH10.pdf). You could probably do worse than copying them. Be aware that the size of the data will expand by about 33%.